# The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'EmployeeID'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Request URL:http://localhost:51536/Employee/AddUpdateEmployee/2

**Route Config**

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

**Controller Action Method**

```
[ActionName("AddUpdateEmployee"), HttpGet]
public ActionResult AddUpdate(Int64 EmployeeID)
{
    var data = (new EmployeeDb()).GetEmployee(EmployeeID);
    return View("~/Views/Employee/_AddUpdateView.cshtml", data);
}
```

When I check the url in browser, i get this error: **The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'EmployeeID'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because according to your route when you do `/2` it thinks of it as value of `/{id}` means `id` but in action the parameter name is `EmployeeID` so it will be `null`

**Solution 1:**

```
public ActionResult AddUpdate(Int64 EmployeeID)
```

change to

```
public ActionResult AddUpdate(Int64 id)
```

**Solution 2:**

send values like

http://localhost:51536/Employee/AddUpdateEmployee?EmployeeID=2